# Show and hide element on hover/click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element (X) which I would like to hide when hover over another element(Y) and show it when the mouse leave the element(Y). I have this working, but I would also like to hide that same element(X) when you click the element (Y) and not show it again when you leave it.

I hope you understand, could you please help?

This is what I have now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SA_SD_1").hover(function() {
    $(".pleaseselect").hide();
  }, function() {
    $(".pleaseselect").show();
  });

  $("#SA_SD_1").click(function() {
    $(".pleaseselect").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be really helpful if you can add your full HTML, CSS, if any and make a working [mcve].

Comment: Would be a lot easier to understand what you want if we see what you have, please include your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some flag to check if "Y" element clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $("#SA_SD_1").hover(function() {
        $(".pleaseselect").hide();
    }, function() {
        if (!clicked) $(".pleaseselect").show();
    });
    $("#SA_SD_1").click(function() {
        clicked = true;
        $(".pleaseselect").hide();
    });
});
```

Or use remove() method to kill "X" element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SA_SD_1").hover(function() {
        $(".pleaseselect").hide();
    }, function() {
        $(".pleaseselect").show();
    });
    $("#SA_SD_1").click(function() {
        $(".pleaseselect").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot! I am totally new to jQuery and didn't know I can use it like this :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SA_SD_1").hover(function() {
    $(".pleaseselect").addClass('hide');
  }, function() {
    $(".pleaseselect").removeClass('hide');
  });

  $("#SA_SD_1").click(function() {
    $(".pleaseselect").toggleClass('hide-on-click');
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.hide-on-click {
  display: none !important;
}
```